# Having multiple independent emails appear in one thread

Tags: header, smtp

My error reporting system sends an email for each exception - every unique error (combination of filename, line number, exception class) gets a unique ID. I'd like my mail client to group messages with the same ID into one thread.

According to the spec (assuming I'm reading it right), the first message in the thread needs to have "Message-ID: " set to the ID, and all following messages need "In-Reply-To: ".

The problem is that each message is sent independently, so I don't know which is "first" and which is "following". I've tried setting both headers on all messages, but (in thunderbird at least) each message still ends up in its own thread :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out between writing the question and hitting "post" :D

Having only "References" and "In-Reply-To" will trigger threading in thunderbird, even with no original "Message-ID" -- thunderbird will assume that the original message was deleted, and promote the first response to the top of the tree with other responses below it.